# Why do we pronounce "ed" in Naked/Wretched as /id/ and not /t/?

Tags: grammar

the rule is if the final consonant sound is voiceless we pronounce /ed/ as /t/ like pluck/plucked (pluck/t/) and it applies to adjectives as well according to this website http://www.grammar.cl/english/pronunciation-ed.htm

Comment: Possibly because it's pronounced as two syllables, (with the accent on the second syllable) instead of one syllable (with the accent on the first syllable)?  For example, yes, "stewed" is pronounced (more or less) as "stew/t/", but "limited" is voiced as /ed/.  I'd like to say there is a rule that words which end in certain letters are always pronounced the same when you add -ed to the end, but unfortunately every one I think of has many exceptions.

Comment: 'Naked' isn't a variant of nake, so the rule doesn't apply there.  Wretched is one of those funny words ([blessed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/pronunciation-of-blessed) is another one that comes to mind) where it could (and possibly should) be pronounced according to the rule (wretch't, blest), but for reasons isn't.  Contrast with 'retched' which *is* pronounced as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because words like "naked" or "wretched" are pronounced as two syllables, (with the accent on the second syllable) instead of one syllable (with the accent on the first syllable)? For example "stewed" is pronounced (more or less) as "stew/t/", but "limited" is voiced as /ed/.

I'd like to say there is a rule that words which end in certain letters are always pronounced the same when you add -ed to the end, but unfortunately every one I think of has many exceptions.  In some cases you can deliberately accent the second syllable to make the word sound more formal or archaic, for example:

> Congratulations to you and your new spouse on this **blessED** day.
>
> My **learnED** colleague insists that global warming is a myth, but thousands of pages of evidence tell a different story.